# Cleaning bike rental stations in Europe question

Tags: discussion, list-questions

I'm of the mind to clean up the [bike rental stations in Europe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/250/which-european-cities-have-bike-rental-stations-for-tourists) question. It has grown out of proportion and is barely useful. I don't want to delete it outright, it still can be useful, if updated occasionally (realistically though, probably not going to happen).

Basically, create one answer with a laundry list of cities grouped by country, with little to no additional information for each (besides a link, obviously), to keep it short. All other answers will then be deleted -- they are community wiki, so no reputation change will take place anyway.

Thoughts? Suggestions what to include and what to omit?

If no one objects, this will be taken care of in a week or so.

**Update:**
The question is now locked, but not deleted, with a note on its historical significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it community wiki as it is now but lock the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question "eliciting list-style answers", which per [FAQ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) is not welcome. Hence I am surprised that is has not yet been closed.

I would suggest that you close it and keep it under the pile. The list of answers can be extended ad eternam. It is very difficult to read with the interspersed pictures and it will continue to grow ...

The better approach would be to ask something like "I am going to city XYZ. Is there a bike rental station in this city?"

Comment: It's one of the most voted questions on the site and bothers me like an unsightly wart. Perhaps closing it is for the best though. I'll wait for some other opinions before figuring out what to do.

Comment: A high number of votes. So what? The most voted question is about poo. Is that something to be proud of?

Comment: SO has a special close mode for things that are no longer a good fit, maybe we could use something like that here to indicate it was a popular question but not the style we now support?

Answer (score 0):

It's too broad to be a Q&A question. But it can be succesfully splited.

Note that while the question 'how do I rent a bike in [country]?' may be a list questions, usually for the [city] it's not. For example, in Nuremberg there's the only one bike rental station 'Norris bike', and in Warsaw 'Venturilo'.

However, if there's a single bike rental network for the whole given country, create the canonical question for the whole country.